# How to move underline using border-bottom to make it look like a underline using box-shadow inset?

Tags: html, css, border, box-shadow

**Simple question:**

[image]

Can I make the underline using `border-bottom` (the ones on the right side) look exactly like the ones using `box-shadow` (the ones on the left side)?

I need it to be CSS only. And it may span across multiple lines as you can see from the snippet.

Basically I need to move the border-bottom a little bit up and not mess with everything else.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova');

div.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 420px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div.flex2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  color: rgb(60,128,124);
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a.boxShadow {
  color: darkGrey;
  text-decoration: none;  
  line-height: 26px;
  
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px white, inset 0 -4px 0 rgb(60,128,124);
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

a.borderBottom {
  color: darkGrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
  
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(60,128,124);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <h2>
    <a class="boxShadow">Hello gjq box-shadow</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>
    <a class="borderBottom">Hello border-bottom</a>
  </h2>
</div>

<div class="flex2">
  <h2>
    <a class="boxShadow">Hello gjq box-shadow</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>
    <a class="borderBottom">Hello border-bottom</a>
  </h2>
</div>
```

**REASON FOR THIS QUESTION (BROWSER CONSISTENCY):**

The `box-shadow` example does exactly what I want, but it does not look good on Edge (and I'm afraid other browsers might not render it properly as well). It looks perfect on recente versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari though.

On Edge, the `box-shadow` example looks like this (see small line leaking at the bottom):

[image]

On the other hand, `border-bottom` seems to render consistently across browsers. But I can't get the underline in the position that I need.

Comment: No...you can't. A border is related to the element's sides....not the content within. Also they are 100% width of the element.

Comment: Currently in the latest spec - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset

Answer (score 1):

Gradient can do this

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova');

div.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 420px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div.flex2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  color: rgb(60,128,124);
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a.boxShadow {
  color: darkGrey;
  text-decoration: none;  
  line-height: 26px;
  
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px white, inset 0 -4px 0 rgb(60,128,124);
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

a.borderBottom {
  color: darkGrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
  
  background:
   linear-gradient(rgb(60,128,124),rgb(60,128,124)) 
    bottom 1px center/ /* Position */
    100% 2px  /*width height*/
   no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <h2>
    <a class="boxShadow">Hello gjq box-shadow</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>
    <a class="borderBottom">Hello border-bottom</a>
  </h2>
</div>

<div class="flex2">
  <h2>
    <a class="boxShadow">Hello gjq box-shadow</a>
  </h2>
  <h2>
    <a class="borderBottom">Hello border-bottom</a>
  </h2>
</div>
```